# Slow average QPS with Google App Engine. Is it normal?

Tags: python, django, performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have deployed a Python App Engine module in production and we are getting an average of 1.5 QPS. We currently need to handle 50 QPS and we plan to handle 3000 QPS at the end of next month and much more if our business grow.

To handle 50 QPS, we currently have about 30 F1 instances. The job of each instance is to parse a json file which is an array of 40 "events" and we store each of them in the DataStore using ndb.put_multi.

We can see on Google Trace that it takes about 5 seconds to start all the "put calls" in parallel to the datastore (each call then takes 200ms which is fair).

To sum up, my app does not do much processing and is quite light. Is it normal to have 1.5 QPS / instance for this kind of app? If yes, app engine would cost us about $100,000 for 3,000 QPS which is unbelievable.

PS : We are using Django 1.7 as our framework

Update : We made additional tests with webapp2 only and one write in the datastore for each requests. We are at about 4.5 QPS only with F1 instances.

Comment: How big is the json file and when you say 'start all the "put calls" in parallel', do you mean 5s for the 40 event entities?  Have you tried `put_multi_async()`? (I'm not familiar with Django).

Comment: The file is around 4kb. It is 200 ms for each put to the datastore (each put can add up to 10 entities by default I think). There are 4 RPC to the datastore which seems to really start 5 seconds after put_multi is called.

Comment: Strange. It sounds more like something in the way Django is mapping to the Datastore API as I wouldn't expect that kind of behaviour from ndb. Are you using django-nonrel or something like [Djangae](https://github.com/potatolondon/djangae)?

Comment: I am using ndb directly.

Comment: Even stranger. If you're not using the returned keys immediate, I would try  `put_multi_async()` instead.

Comment: That sounds excessively long "about 5 seconds to start all the "put calls""  if they where complex entities you might get a big overhead encoding everything, I suggest you put a lot of logging from the start of request, each stage up to the put.  And I would agree using put_multi_async.  - Not really enough info here to suggest much else.

Comment: I suggest you create a simple test case which only puts the records and time that directly without any other activity. "Google trace"? do you mean appstats or cloud trace ?

Comment: I'm guessing you need bigger instance. Parsing (lots of) json is cpu intensive.